# How to pass position to RecyclerView.ViewHolder?

Tags: android

How do I pass the current position to my class that extends `RecyclerView.ViewHolder`? It needs it in order to create the view programmatically

Comment: in onBindViewHolder you can pass position to your ViewHolder

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type).

Comment: You can save index position in your data model for each item and refer to it inside ViewHolder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RecyclerView` holder already has `getAdapterPosition()` and `getLayoutPosition()` methods
From the Docs:

```
final int   getAdapterPosition()
Returns the Adapter position of the item represented by this ViewHolder.

final int   getLayoutPosition()
Returns the position of the ViewHolder in terms of the latest layout pass.
```